# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{\gcd{(k,n)}} $ is divisible by $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a, n \in\mathbb{N}^*$. Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{\gcd{(k,n)}} $$ is divisible by $n$.

My idea: That sum is $$\sum _{d\mid n} d\cdot \phi(d) \cdot a^{\frac{n}{d}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{(k,n)} = \sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{\ \ \ \ k=1 \\ (k,n) = d}^na^{(k,n)}=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{\ \ \ \ k=1 \\ (\frac kd,\frac nd) = 1}^na^{(k,n)} = \sum_{d\mid n} \varphi\left(\frac nd\right)a^{d}$$
Then, see this [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217154/seeking-a-proof-of-sum-dn-phi-fracndad-equiv-0-modn-where-phi/1594798#1594798).